# The dimension of the solution space of $x^2y'' − 4xy' + 6y = 0$ on $(−1, 1)$ is?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential, change-of-basis

> What's the dimension of the solution space of $x^2y'' − 4xy' + 6y = 0$ on $(−1, 1)$?

The answer is $3$.

How is this possible? Isn't the basis $\{x^2 , x^3\}$?

Answer (score 2):

What about this solution?
$$
y(x) = \begin{cases}
x^3, & x \ge 0
\\
-x^3, & x < 0
\end{cases}
$$